# How casual friendly is The Secret World?

Tags: the-secret-world

I'm considering The Secret World as a new game to play, as the setting fascinates me. However, I'm hesitant to pick up a MMO, because the time I can invest in it is limited.

Can I enjoy all of the content in a reasonable amount of time, if I'm only able to spend ~10 Hours per week on the game?

Comment: Welp, if I committed that much time to a single game, I wouldn't call myself a casual at it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main story line assuming that you complete the main story quests and enough side quests to be sufficiently levelled to complete the main story quests will take about 40 hours of continual play approximately. Every quest in the main story line can be completed solo, although like all MMORPGs there is a benefit to playing in a party.

PvP is very much influenced by character progression, as having greater progression in the game will result in having more abilities available, thus doing more damage or healing. PvP is possible at low levels but having more ability points and better gear will yield better results in the battlegrounds.

There are "dungeons"/instances in game throughout the story which require group play and there is a random dungeon finder [available in game](http://www.thesecretworld.com/news/group_finder_comes_with_digging_deeper) to find groups:

[image: image of looking for group tool]

Again, these instances are not *required* for the main story, although they are all tied into the main story.

In contrast, there are also instances in the game throughout the story which are enforced single player as well, in which you enter alone to complete a task. Again these instances are not *required* for the main story.

There is not much of a requirement to ever join a guild, with the content currently available in game. Obviously being an MMORPG the game is improved by playing with friends but even for the solo play the quest progression and story line are definitely a lot of fun.

Comment: Some of the main story quests are solo dungeons, even if you're in a party. The other members of your party will be given their own instance and you *can't* complete it together.

Comment: There is now a "Dungeon Finder" in the form of a third party addon called "Field Agent Locator", which is widely used by players. It can be found on Curse: http://www.curse.com/tsw-mods/tsw/field-agent-locator

Comment: As of issue #2, there is now a LFG tool built into the game.

Comment: Shift + C for the Group Finder tool